# how to combine two columns in sqlite in python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

How can I combine two columns in sqlite3? I know I can use `+` in a `select` statement, but when I've tried this code in python :

```
select first+last as name from users
```

it gave me `0`.

I have tried this statement

```
select first||" "||last as name from users
```

I'm getting error.

I want to show firstname and last name in one column, something like this:

```
'tara.panagop@where.com', 'tara panagop',
```

Comment: Did you look at the SQLite syntax page?  http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html seems pretty clear.  "but I'm getting error" is not clear.  You might want to provide the smallest example of actual code you're running and the actual error you're actually getting.

Answer (score 0):

`as` binds tighter than `||` so this needs parens:

```
select (first||" "||last) as name from users
```

---

ecape `"` in quotes as `\"`:

```
cur.execute("select (first||\" \"||last) as name from users")
```

Comment: this is my actual code cur.execute("select first || ""||last as name from users") and i'll get this error after running my code :Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#62>", line 1, in <module> cur.execute("select first || ""||last as name from users") sqlite3.OperationalError: near "||": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

If you have null rows you might want to try

```
select (coalesce(first,'')||" "||coalesce(last,'')) as name from users
```